# importing from source results in parent module not found while handling absolute import

Tags: python

I have the following folder structure;

```
app/
ext/
  gredis/
    gredis.py
```

I have the full path of gredis.py in `/Users/blah/blah/blah/ext/gredis/gredis.py`

However, when I try to import `ext.gredis.gredis` module by using;

```
imp.load_source('ext.gredis.gredis', path)
```

I have the following error;

```
RuntimeWarning: Parent module 'ext.gredis' not found while handling absolute import
```

Do I need to first import ext.gredis ?

NOTE: All folders have `__init__.py`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you post the code that reproduces the error? This works for me:

```
$ tree
.
+-- app
¦   +-- test.py
+-- ext
¦   +-- gredis
¦   ¦   +-- gredis.py
¦   ¦   +-- gredis.pyc
¦   +-- test.py
+-- test.py

$ for path in test.py app/test.py ext/test.py; do python $path; done;
<module 'ext.gredis.gredis' from '/tmp/bla/ext/gredis/gredis.pyc'>
<module 'ext.gredis.gredis' from '/tmp/bla/ext/gredis/gredis.pyc'>
<module 'ext.gredis.gredis' from '/tmp/bla/ext/gredis/gredis.pyc'>
```

And test.py contains:

```
import imp
print(imp.load_source('ext.gredis.gredis', '/tmp/bla/ext/gredis/gredis.py'))
```

This works in both python 2.x and 3.x.

Answer (score 1):

My discovered solution was to assure that the first argument to imp.load_source (i.e. a name for your module) contained no periods. No idea why this matters, but hope it helps someone